# $\arctan$ mutiple of $\tan$

Tags: calculus

I am evaluating an integral, and do not know how to deal with mult of $\tan$ inside of an $\arctan$.
This could not be simplified just to $x$. The integral bounds are $0$ and $\pi/2$. At $\pi/2$ $\tan$ is not determined.
This is the result of integrating to which I need to apply the bounds.

$$ Arctan[2/5 Tan[x]] $$

Comment: Please improve formatting and add your attempts. Let us recall that a function does not need to be defined at the endpoints of an interval to be integrable over such interval, so $\tan(\pi/2)=\text{undef}$ is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Additionally, if $f$ is an integrable function over the interval $(-a,a)$ and $f$ is an odd function, $$ \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx = 0 $$ by symmetry.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan(\frac25\tan(x)) = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\arctan(\frac25 t) = \lim\limits_{s\to\infty}\arctan(s) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @achillehui This is so cute! I have not seen this before. My calc roots are not deep yet. Thanks a lot!